# Conversion between running and stationary bike?

Tags: running, crossfit

I have just started doing CrossFit. Many of the workouts include a running component, such as start and end with 800m runs. Due to a knee injury, I can't handle the impact of running, so I have been using a stationary bike.

Is there an appropriate conversion I can use to determine the distance I should be biking to be equivalent to the distance everyone else is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically it’s around 3x for a bike, so a 30mi bike ride would be a similar workout to 10mile run.
Whilst there is no true direct comparison due to the different muscle groups used (such as upper body recruitment when running) you can monitor heart rate zones. I.e If they are running for 3:30 in zone 4 then you can match that on the bike. 
I personally tend to find my max HR to be slightly lower on a bike than running so you may need to factor that in.